Why skip tachnun on shavuos tashlumin?
B"H
Every chag has tashlumin, "make up time", to bring the required offerings on it, all 7 days.
Even though shavuos is only 1 day, for 6 days after it, in the times of the Beis Hamikdash, people would be able to bring the necessary sacrifices.
Nowadays, many Jewish communities that I'm aware of do not say tachnun for 7 days beginning with shavuos. Why? We don't offer sacrifices anymore.
On the chag itself I can understand why we don't say tachnun, since we make kiddish, refrain from melacha, and the entire day is "holy".
However, during the make-up time days, we do so melacha, we don't make kiddish, and they are in general just regular days.
This is also unlike the tashlumin for other holidays, which we don't say tachanun on, because that are actually a part of the festival itself (chol hamoed).
So why skip say tachnun on the shavuos tashlumin days, which are seemingly just regular days (only that if there was a beis hamikdash we would be able to offer the necessary sacrifices)?
Similar question may apply to pesach sheini, although that holiday has it's own actions that we do on it even nowadays (eating matzah), so it would make more sense why we treat it as a holiday now and don't say tachnun, but I'm not aware of any unique action that people are supposed to do on the tashlumin days of shavuos that would warrant treating them as their own holiday to not say tachnun

Note the question is likely better than any answer, as indeed until quite recently the overwhelming majority of classical Jewish authorities do not mention omitting tachanun on these days. It was indeed only ~50 years ago that Birnbaum siddur was standard across the USA and it doesn't mention this practice at all.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

There are many days which are "seemingly just regular days" and without "any unique action" on which tachanun is not said - e.g. tachanun is not said for the entire month of Nissan nor on the days between Yom Kippur and Succot.
Those whose custom is to omit tachanun until 12th or 13th Sivan do so because they regard the six days following Shavuot on which the festival offerings could be brought as being essentially the Shavuot equivalent to Chol Ha Moe'ed on Pesach and Succot. Those whose custom is to omit tachanun only on Isru Chag Shavuot do not agree with that view.
See Mishnah Berurah 131:36
(לו) עד אחר שבועות - ויש מקומות נוהגין שלא ליפול כל הששה ימים שאחר שבועות מפני שהקרבנות של חג השבועות היה להם תשלומין כל ז':
From Rosh Chodesh until after Shavuot. There are places whose custom is to omit tachanun for the six days after Shavuot [as well as on isru chag], because the yom tov sacrifices of Shavuot may be brought for seven compensatory days.

The reason in the MB just says that because the sacrifices were brought all 7.. But we don't have sacrifices now, so what does that mean for us?

@Awtsmoos--עצמות Indeed. There are many whose custom is only to omit tachanun on isru chag (עד אחר שבועות) and not for a further six days after Shavuot

as you pointed out the days after shavuos are days in which the sacrifice of shavuos can be made up. This ability to bring the sacrifice makes those days into joyous occasions. While we cannot bring sacrifices today the reason for those days being joyous has not changed. Likewise during the initial days of Nissan we do not say tachanun when the heads of the tribes brought their sacrifices and those exact ones were not brought again.
Likewise we learn from shavuos many of the customs that apply to marriage. And this the days days of tachanun are the 7 days of blessing after the Jewish people were so to speak married to Hashem by accepting the Torah. Likewise we skip tachanun during the week of sheva brachos. Calling a shavuos a marriage and learning customs for marriage from it is brought down by Rabbi Samson ben Tzadok, student of Maharam of Rothenberg, in his sefer Tashbatz Katan #464, 5.

Learning customs for marriage is the opposite of learning customs of shavuot (and is anachronistic, since Tashbetz/Maharam don't make the extension you are trying to make)

"This ability to bring the sacrifice makes those days into joyous occasions." The question remains, why would it? As pointed out in the comments above, even in Temple times while offering sacrifices they allowed eulogies and mourning on these days. How much more so is there no celebratory effect on people who aren't bringing sacrifices on a particular day (eg. they offered their shavuot sacrifices yesterday and went home).

@Dude can you please post Tashbatz Katan #464, 5 which you cite. Without seeing the source I find your answer at the very borderline of "not useful" - by virtue of being little more than argumentative.

@Dude you say we learn from shavuos many of the customs that apply to marriage Can you please provide one or two examples.
